# Tracking redirect links in Sitecore 8.0

Tags: sitecore, tracking, sitecore-xdb

Suppose we have two links on a page, which redirect to the same page. How can we find that user came to the redirect page after click on which link using Sitecore analytics? If possible then please provide me with all steps.

Comment: Grammar, and a better title.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to process the link server side than you can set a Event of whatever.

Another option is to track client side events. Set a click event on both links and submit it to Sitecore:
See for example:

[client-side-tracking-with-sitecore](https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/client-side-tracking-with-sitecore-dms/)

[Sitecore-Client-Event-Tracker](https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Client-Event-Tracker)